# Only set time of timestamp in select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have an app where the user can define when he is working: e.g. from 8am to 5pm. In my MySQL DB I have two timestamp fields. How can I only set the time, but not the date? I need this because only the time is important. I just want to know from when to when the user is working. Date itself is irrelevant.

I tried something like this but my database refuses it:

```
0000-00-00 08:00:00
```

This is my select statement:

```
# check if there is already an appointment, if yes, return it
select * 
from ios_appointments a join ios_workinghours h using(workerid_fk)
where workerid_fk = 1
AND h.start <= '08:30:00' AND h.end >= '10:00:00'
AND (
    a.start BETWEEN '2012-12-24 08:30:00'  AND  '2012-12-24 10:00:00'
    OR  a.end   BETWEEN '2012-12-24 08:30:00'  AND  '2012-12-24 10:00:00'
    OR (a.start < '2012-12-24 08:30:00' AND a.end > '2012-12-24 10:00:00')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use MySQL's [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) data type; use [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time.html) instead:

> MySQL retrieves and displays `TIME` values in `'HH:MM:SS'` format (or `'HHH:MM:SS'` format for large hours values). `TIME` values may range from `'-838:59:59'` to `'838:59:59'`. The hours part may be so large because the `TIME` type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).

Therefore:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ios_workinghours
  MODIFY start TIME,
  MODIFY end   TIME
```

Comment: Exactelly what I've been looking for! I didn't know the `TIME` datatype exists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CURTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time) to insert current time, in your table.

> Returns the current time as a value in 'HH:MM:SS' or HHMMSS.uuuuuu
>   format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or
>   numeric context. The value is expressed in the current time zone.

Further, you may [refer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Well, I don't need the current time, although the format is correct. I need to be able to save a specific time in the database in the CURTIME()-format.

Comment: but, in your question, you said, you are unable to save time.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what your are asking for but u can use DATE_FORMAT

```
select * 
  from ios_appointments a join ios_workinghours h using(workerid_fk)
  where workerid_fk = 1
        AND DATE_FORMAT(h.start , '%H:%i:%s') <= '08:30:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(h.end , '%H:%i:%s') >= '10:00:00'
        AND (
          a.start BETWEEN '2012-12-24 08:30:00'  AND  '2012-12-24 10:00:00'
          OR  a.end   BETWEEN '2012-12-24 08:30:00'  AND  '2012-12-24 10:00:00'
          OR (a.start < '2012-12-24 08:30:00' AND a.end > '2012-12-24 10:00:00')
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will solve your problem-

```
select * 
from ios_appointments a join ios_workinghours h using(workerid_fk)
where workerid_fk = 1
AND date_format( h.start, "%h:%i:%s")  <= '08:30:00' AND date_format( h.end, "%h:%i:%s") >= '10:00:00'
AND (
    a.start BETWEEN '2012-12-24 08:30:00'  AND  '2012-12-24 10:00:00'
    OR  a.end   BETWEEN '2012-12-24 08:30:00'  AND  '2012-12-24 10:00:00'
    OR (a.start < '2012-12-24 08:30:00' AND a.end > '2012-12-24 10:00:00')
)
```